# sql scalar function not returning correct value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written a scalar function to try to return a datetime that is rounded down to a specified multiple.

The function is based from this formula

```
select dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute, 0, '2014-01-05 12:23:05') / 30) * 30, 0)
```

that correctly returns

> 2014-01-05 12:00:00.000

I tried to write it as a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time datetime, @RoundTo float) RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RoundedTime datetime
    SET @RoundedTime = dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute, 0, @Time) / @RoundTo) * @RoundTo, 0) 
    RETURN @RoundedTime
END
```

but when I run a select statement

```
select dbo.roundtime('2014-01-05 12:23:05',30)
```

or even when I force the time into a datetime format to match the definition

```
select businessusers.dbo.roundtime(cast('2014-01-05 12:23:05' as datetime),30)
```

it returns this:

> 2014-01-05 12:23:00.000

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your "trick" depends exclusively in `INTEGER` division, which isn't the case in your function because `@RoundTo` is a `FLOAT`. Change it to an `INT` to make it work. On an unrelated note, I recommend against the use of this type of scalar functions as a general note, since they can affect performance

Comment: thank you. Put your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @Lamak Could you elaborate a bit on your recommendation? What would you do instead of a scalar function, to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method of rounding relies on the division's being integral, [as Lamak has correctly noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274101/sql-scalar-function-not-returning-correct-value#comment39383939_25274101).

In SQL Server, division is integral when both operands are integers.

In your first example, the result of `DATEDIFF` is `int` by definition and the `30` is recognised by the parser as an `int` too. Therefore, the query works as expected.

In your function, however, one of the operands of the division, `@RoundTo`, is declared to be a `float`. That prescribes SQL Server to use normal division, preventing any rounding from happening.

There are basically two ways of resolving this. One is, obviously, to change the type of `@RoundTo` to an integer type. (Usually `int` works fine, even though its capacity may appear too large for this use case.)

The other method, if for some reason you want to stick with the `float` (e.g. you want to be able to round down to the nearest half-minute or some such interval), would be to apply the [`FLOOR()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx) function to the division's result:

```
floor(datediff(minute, 0, @Time) / @RoundTo) * @RoundTo
```

However, if `@RoundTo` was not a whole number, the result of multiplication by `@RoundTo` might not be whole either. To make the resulting intervals consistent, you would probably need to convert the minutes to seconds at the final stage:

```
dateadd(second, floor(datediff(minute, 0, @Time) / @RoundTo) * @RoundTo * 60, 0)
```